# QMessageBox не в главном потоке

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
import time
import sys, threading
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication


class Global:
    def __init__(self):
        for c in MyClass, MainWindow:
            cl = c()
            setattr(self, c.__name__, cl)
            setattr(cl, 'global_', self)


class MyClass:
    def work(self):
        for r in range(100):
            if r == 2:
                self.global_.MainWindow.SignalBox.emit('MyClass NO PAUSE')  # need pause !!!
            else:
                print(r)
            time.sleep(1)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    SignalBox = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.lab = QtGui.QLabel()
        lay = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.lab)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        self.msgBox = lambda txt: getattr(QtGui.QMessageBox(), 'information')(self, txt, txt)
        self.Signal.connect(self.lab.setText)
        self.SignalBox.connect(self.msgBox)

    def thread_no_wait(self):
        self.global_.MainWindow.SignalBox.emit('MyClass PAUSE OK')
        threading.Thread(target=self.global_.MyClass.work).start()

    def thread_main(self):
        def my_work():
            for r in range(100):
                self.Signal.emit(str(r))
                time.sleep(1)
        threading.Thread(target=my_work).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = Global()
    g.MainWindow.show()
    g.MainWindow.thread_main()
    g.MainWindow.thread_no_wait()
    app.exec_()
```

`MyClass.work` выполняется в отдельном потоке без `join`
Необходимо, чтобы `MyClass` приостанавливался, если он вызывает `QMessageBox`
Если определить `QMessageBox` вне `MainWindow`, будет вызвана ошибка

```
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread.
```

А при таком вызове `QMessageBox`  вызывается в отдельном потоке и работа не приостанавливается

Answer (score 1):

```
<code>
class MyClass:
    def work(self):
        for r in range(100):
            if r == 2:
                self.msgBox('MyClass PAUSE')
            else:
                print(r)
            time.sleep(1)

    def msgBox(self, txt):
        s = self.global_.MainWindow.stop
        self.global_.MainWindow.SignalBox.emit(txt)
        while self.global_.MainWindow.stop == s: pass
        while self.global_.MainWindow.stop: pass

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
 ...
    def __init__(self):
 ...

        self.stop = False
        def box(txt):
            self.stop = True
            getattr(QtGui.QMessageBox(), 'information')(self, txt, txt)
            self.stop = False

        self.msgBox = box
...
</code>
```

Вот такой затычкой останавливает:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808990/qmessagebox-in-other-thread